# Intel RST on ubuntu for NVME (not sata/ahci)

Tags: raid, nvme, ahci, rst

Plenty of questions surrounding this and people say switch to ahci. That would be awesome, but my nvme evo 980s don't have ahci options in the asus rog bios on the wifi gaming d4. AHCI is a sata only technology?

So that's it? No bios raid for me?

Comment: Intel RST (Rapid Storage Technology) is not supported by Linux in any form.  You would have to disable RST in your BIOS (probably a switch) and install Linux in non-RST form.  You could then do 'raid' by using LVM and having multiple disks added to the LVM array.  However, this is complicated and can break things if a disk goes away.  (Intel RST is just Software Raid, like doing it yourself with dmraid or LVM)

Comment: What settings do you have? Not sure why AHCI required if only NVMe as that is a separate driver. Have you updated UEFI firmware to latest available. And checked if NVMe drives have latest firmware. Even new drives may need update. How to update Samsung:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_state_drive & 
https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/

Comment: I think it's software raid+ though? I've got the 12900k, and I *think* there's at least some magic baked into the cpu? It could be marketing buzzwords, but I believe the processors have integrations for vmd specifically.

Comment: I want to use it with windows @oldfred. Perhaps there's other raid technologies I should use. A lot of folks were saying you can swap to ahci without data loss. I've got backups, but wanted to avoid a reinstall

Comment: Raid On for NVMe works for me with Lubuntu 22.04 LTS in a Dell Latitude 3520 (with generation 11 Intel i3 CPU). I can keep the pre-installed Windows (I upgraded 10 --> 11) and use the linux kernel VMD driver. There are more details at [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1543006&page=91&p=14097006#post14097006)

Comment: @ThomasWard It is wrong that Linux doesn't support RST. In lspci on my laptop it shows `SATA Controller [RST mode]` ;-) It is not that straight forward. The problem is only with dual boot and solvable, but sometimes not very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the usual, I get a downvote for a valid question and not only that, people are pretentious and wrong. It's ok to make mistakes, but the abhorrent negativity people bring to this makes it not ok. There's so much bad info out there and people just lean into it.

```
sudo IMSM_NO_PLATFORM=1 mdadm --verbose --assemble --scan
```

I can't comment as to installation with this method, but I run linux on a usb stick and can see my windows volumes now.

If you downvoted this, you're wrong. Seek to understand and be kind to people.