# How to fix Ubuntu Boot up Message "Reset System"

Tags: boot, grub2

I have an Acer aspire V3-372T with an M.2 SATA SSD and windows 10 home with Ubuntu 20.04 on it with a gpt partition table and UEFI firmware. and when I try to boot Ubuntu, I recieve an error message of `reset system` on a black screen, and the computer restarts. I have tried reinstalling ubuntu, recovering grub, and turning secure boot off, but none of those worked. I can't turn off secure boot, and I have tried ctrl+s in bios, but those didn't work.

Comment: Best to say what you have done, so we do not suggest same things.  If Secure boot on, it would have to be UEFI. Many Acer require you to turn on Secure boot and set "trust" on ubuntu entry in UEFI settings. These links may have more info. Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702
Acer Aspire A515-54G Newer Acer -  CTRL S on the main Tab in BIOS to get the option to change SATA to AHCI
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211911/cannot-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-a515-54g-laptop-hard-drive-not-detected

Comment: @oldfred I tried ctrl+s in the bios, but that didn't work for me, and some of the options in those articles are off limits for me, and I can't change them, like turning secure boot off and chanaging SATA to AHCI. I also use an m.2 SATA SSD, not an AHCI SSD, so that would cause failure to boot.

Comment: The M.2 can be either SATA with AHCI or NVMe with vmd driver. My new Dell uses NVMe (only) and a vmd driver, so it does not need AHCI. Main issue I had was turning bitlocker off in Windows, so installer could see the Windows install and not erase it. But I had to use 22.04 to have latest kernel & drivers. Your 20.04 may be too old as it can take a year or more for Linux software to catch up with very latest hardware.

Comment: The VMD driver may work with SATA also. It is RAID, but works with one drive. Windows has been using the "RAID" driver even if one drive, and that was why in past we had to convert to AHCI & install Windows AHCI driver. More info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422146/intel-rst-on-ubuntu-for-nvme-not-sata-ahci Linux has had VMD driver for a while, but not sure Ubuntu included it in older versions. Try 22.04 to see if that works.